# Template variables and the variables that can store template variables

Tags: c#, templates, types

There is two variables

```
 basic<type1> type_1;
 basic<type2> type_2;
```

I want to this two variables to store another variable like this

```
basic<type1> type_1;
basic<type2> type_2;

var type = type_1 or type_2 // What type of variable should be declared?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object` or `dynamic`.

Also, if `basic<T>` inherits from let say `basic` you will be able to use `basic` as the variable type.

Comment: correct, but incomplete... Indeed *any* base class would do (i.e.for  `basic<T> : root1 : root2 : root3` you can use all rootX in addition to object)